# Why is C function so long?

Tags: c

I'm coming from a script guy, used to functions within 50 lines.

And when I see frequently functions over 200 lines,I'm really having a hard time reading it.

Is this normal at all?

Comment: How long are the functions, depends on the device in front of the machine...

Comment: Sounds like it is normal for you to have difficulties with long functions. It is also normal for me.

Comment: 200 lines, with brackets on seperate lines and lots of empty lines I guess?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the language that makes functions "long" - you can write long functions in any reasonable language, and, ideally, should refactor them into smaller, more understandable and maintainable functions in most languages.

Comment: But most open source projects in c have many many long functions..

Comment: @mysql_go: And not all open source projects have the absolute best code ;)  This is a function of the developer, NOT the language.